# Reading, comparing and merging multiple files in Java

Tags: java, memory, io, cpu

Given there are some files Customer-1.txt, Customer-2.txt and Customer-3.txt and these files have the following content:

Customer-1.txt

```
1|1|MARY|SMITH  
2|1|PATRICIA|JOHNSON  
4|2|BARBARA|JONES
```

Customer-2.txt

```
1|1|MARY|SMITH  
2|1|PATRICIA|JOHNSON   
3|1|LINDA|WILLIAMS  
4|2|BARBARA|JONES
```

Customer-3.txt

```
2|1|PATRICIA|JOHNSON   
3|1|LINDA|WILLIAMS  
5|2|ALEXANDER|ANDERSON
```

These files have a lot of duplicate data, but it is possible that each file contains some data that is unique.

And given that the actual files are **sorted**, big (a few GB each file) and there are many files...

**Then what is the:

a) memory cheapest

b) cpu cheapest

c) fastest

way in Java to create one file out of these three files that will contain all the unique data of each file sorted and concatenated like such:**

Customer-final.txt

```
1|1|MARY|SMITH  
2|1|PATRICIA|JOHNSON
3|1|LINDA|WILLIAMS  
4|2|BARBARA|JONES
5|2|ALEXANDER|ANDERSON
```

I looked into the following solution https://github.com/upcrob/spring-batch-sort-merge , but I would like to know if its possible to perhaps do it with the FileInputStream and/or a non spring batch solution.

A solution to use an in memory or real database to join them is not viable for my use case due to the size of the files and the absence of an actual database.

Comment: Is the first value a customer ID, and are the files already sorted (numerically) by that first value, as your examples would indicate they are?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, they are sorted already. Thanks for noting, ill add it in the question description.

Comment: i dont think you can achieve this without reading file contents. you hava to read each file and then write the out put to a seperate file.

Comment: If I understood you correctly you could use approach similar to merge sort - which is read one line from each file and find which one is the smallest and write it into some `OutputStream`. The only difference is that you have more than 2 files and you need to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the input files are already sorted, a simple parallel iteration of the files, merging their content, is the *memory cheapest*, *cpu cheapest*, and *fastest* way to do it.

This is a multi-way merge join, i.e. a sort-merge join without the "sort", with elimination of duplicates, similar to a SQL `DISTINCT`.

Here is a version that can do unlimited number of input files (well, as many as you can have open files anyway). It uses a helper class to stage the next line from each input file, so the leading ID value only has to be parsed once per line.

```
private static void merge(StringWriter out, BufferedReader ... in) throws IOException {
    CustomerReader[] customerReader = new CustomerReader[in.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++)
        customerReader[i] = new CustomerReader(in[i]);
    merge(out, customerReader);
}

private static void merge(StringWriter out, CustomerReader ... in) throws IOException {
    List<CustomerReader> min = new ArrayList<>(in.length);
    for (;;) {
        min.clear();
        for (CustomerReader reader : in)
            if (reader.hasData()) {
                int cmp = (min.isEmpty() ? 0 : reader.compareTo(min.get(0)));
                if (cmp < 0)
                    min.clear();
                if (cmp <= 0)
                    min.add(reader);
            }
        if (min.isEmpty())
            break; // all done
        // optional: Verify that lines that compared equal by ID are entirely equal
        out.write(min.get(0).getCustomerLine());
        out.write(System.lineSeparator());
        for (CustomerReader reader : min)
            reader.readNext();
    }
}

private static final class CustomerReader implements Comparable<CustomerReader> {
    private BufferedReader in;
    private String         customerLine;
    private int            customerId;
    CustomerReader(BufferedReader in) throws IOException {
        this.in = in;
        readNext();
    }
    void readNext() throws IOException {
        if ((this.customerLine = this.in.readLine()) == null)
            this.customerId = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        else
            this.customerId = Integer.parseInt(this.customerLine.substring(0, this.customerLine.indexOf('|')));
    }
    boolean hasData() {
        return (this.customerLine != null);
    }
    String getCustomerLine() {
        return this.customerLine;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(CustomerReader that) {
        // Order by customerId only. Inconsistent with equals()
        return Integer.compare(this.customerId, that.customerId);
    }
}
```

**TEST**

```
String file1data = "1|1|MARY|SMITH\n" +
                   "2|1|PATRICIA|JOHNSON\n" +
                   "4|2|BARBARA|JONES\n";
String file2data = "1|1|MARY|SMITH\n" +
                   "2|1|PATRICIA|JOHNSON\n" +
                   "3|1|LINDA|WILLIAMS\n" +
                   "4|2|BARBARA|JONES\n";
String file3data = "2|1|PATRICIA|JOHNSON\n" +
                   "3|1|LINDA|WILLIAMS\n" +
                   "5|2|ALEXANDER|ANDERSON\n";
try (
    BufferedReader in1 = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(file1data));
    BufferedReader in2 = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(file2data));
    BufferedReader in3 = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(file3data));
    StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
) {
    merge(out, in1, in2, in3);
    System.out.print(out);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1|1|MARY|SMITH
2|1|PATRICIA|JOHNSON
3|1|LINDA|WILLIAMS
4|2|BARBARA|JONES
5|2|ALEXANDER|ANDERSON
```

The code merges purely by ID value, and doesn't verify that rest of line is actually equal. Insert code at the `optional` comment to check for that, if needed.

Comment: Very detailed answer and exactly what I am looking for. All my files actually have a sorted unique identifier (Customer files, but also all the other files like for example the Actor files). Am I correct in understand that for each "group"  of files I would have to call the merge function with the group of files?

Comment: That is correct. For each set of similar files that needs to be merged to a single output file, you call merge, e.g. one merge call for Customer files, another merge call for Actor files, and so on...

Comment: FYI: Since your files are large, and likely written one at a time, they might each be stored in contiguous areas on the hard disk. When reading 3 files and writing one file in parallel, the hard disk arm may end up moving a lot. You can minimize that by increasing the buffer size of the `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter` objects from the default 8k to something higher, e.g. 64k (or maybe even 1M?). Increasing it too high will just waste memory without performance improvement.

Comment: Very useful comment. The current biggest hardware bottleneck is memory, so I will try and play around with some different buffer sizes and see what works best for my scenario. Thank you Andreas for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String files[] = {"Customer-1.txt", "Customer-2.txt", "Customer-3.txt"};
    HashMap<Integer, String> customers = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    try {
        String line;
        for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/" + files[i]));
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                Integer uuid = Integer.valueOf(line.split("|")[0]);
                customers.put(uuid, line);
            }
            reader.close();
        }

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("data/Customer-final.txt"));
        Iterator<String> it = customers.values().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) writer.write(it.next() + "\n");

        writer.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you have any cquestions ask me.

Comment: That will load all (unique) lines into memory, so it definitely is not "*a) memory cheapest*". Using `split()` to just extract the first value is not the most efficient way to do that, so it is not "*b) cpu cheapest*". Since you store lines in a `HashSet`, the output will *not be sorted*.